# Copy information from external website to my website

Tags: web-scraping

**Apologies if this is the wrong place to ask and if it is, please do let me know where best to do so.**

I want to write a script that will pull data from `website B` (external site, not owned by myself) and display that data on `website A` (site owned by myself).

Now, I know how to do this programmatically and so my question is more about the legalities of the approach.

For example, Twitter provides API access so that you can embed tweets or a twitter feed into your page. The sites that I would like to pull data from may or may not have such APIs and so I would have to write a `scraper`.

Am I allowed to scrape information from websites and display it on my own site? I will of course make it absolutely clear where the information has come from; I do not intend to use any information and claim that is is my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is generally frowned upon, as you are basically doing the same as copying a CD putting your own label on it and selling it to others (i.e. taking someone else's stuff and pretending it's your own).  I suppose it depends on the licence of the web site you are scraping.  If the web site provides an API (like Twitter), then they probably allow copying.

Comment: Well, everyone will know where the information is coming from - I don't intend to have it displayed as if it was my own content. I get your point, though.